# Overlap unwrapped texture with transparent image

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, transparency, texture-painting

I'm working on a briefcase and want to make it look like a thread has been woven into it. However the only result I can get is based on the already unwrapped texture. How do I simply overlay, and create essentially another uv unwrap? See pictures for details and result im trying to achieve.

Setup

[image: Node setup]
Texture for the leather

[image: Texture]
Result I'm trying to get

[image: Result]
The problem, this happens when I texture paint 1 line on one side.

[image: Problem]

Comment: if you want to paint something new on it, as it won't use the same UV map, you should create a new UV map. But I wodner why you want to paint rather than model your thread in 3D?

Comment: I don't want to paint it, sorry for the confusion. The image is their to demonstrate the problem with the texture i have right now.

Comment: it looks like you're talking about 2 different things, if you want to create a sewing, you could create it in 3D, especially if you want to make close-up shots, and in that case, UVmap has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you want to create a second UV map because by now a single stroke creates multiple strokes on your texture. This can be done in the vertex tab, clicking the plus icon in the UV panel and re-unwrapping with the new UV selected. Don't forget to add an UV input node for every material you have, to indicate which UV map to use in that material and avoid unexpected projections.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for